# Sequential calls with reactor-netty http client seem to free ByteBuf of the first response and causes IllegalReferenceCountException

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I have a requirement to either make two http calls in sequence with one being dependent on another AND in another case to make two parallel calls and combine their results.

For Case1: Sequential calls dependent on one another, I am using "zipWhen" to combine my results together

For Case2: Parallel calls asynchronously, I am using "zip" to subscribe to the publishers of both http requests and combine results.

In both these cases, I have found that the ByteBuf which contains the first response is automatically losing reference when the second calls is made and results in RefCount exceptions when I try to access the first response.

```
(string1, string2) -> StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(string1.getT2().nioBuffer()).toString()
```

I suspect this has to do with responseSingle but I am not sure why this is the case. The reason why I am using responseSingle is because I want both headers and body of the response in response processing.

I am including an edited code sample below for Case1 (Sequential) from the reactor-netty workshop github repo which shows this behaviour:

```
package io.spring.workshop.reactornetty.http;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.netty.DisposableServer;
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient;
import reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;


public class HttpCompressionTests {

    @Test
    public void httpCompressionTest() {
        DisposableServer server =
                HttpServer.create()   // Prepares a HTTP server for configuration.
                          .port(0)    // Configures the port number as zero, this will let the system pick up
                                      // an ephemeral port when binding the server.
                          .handle((req, res) -> res.sendString(Mono.just("compressed response")))
                          .compress(true) // Enables compression.
                          .wiretap(true)  // Applies a wire logger configuration.
                          .bindNow(); // Starts the server in a blocking fashion, and waits for it to finish initializing.

        assertNotNull(server);

        String response =
                HttpClient.create()            // Prepares a HTTP client for configuration.
                          .port(server.port()) // Obtains the server's port and provides it as a port to which this
                                               // client should connect.
                          .compress(true)          // Enables compression.
                          .wiretap(true)           // Applies a wire logger configuration.
                          .get()               // Specifies that GET method will be used.
                          .uri("/test")        // Specifies the path.
                          .responseSingle((res, body) -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(res), body.defaultIfEmpty(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)))   // Receives the response body.
//                          .aggregate()
//                          .asString()
                          .log("http-client")
                          .zipWhen(string1 ->
                              HttpClient.create()            // Prepares a HTTP client for configuration.
                                      .port(server.port()) // Obtains the server's port and provides it as a port to which this
                                      // client should connect.
                                      .compress(true)          // Enables compression.
                                      .wiretap(true)           // Applies a wire logger configuration.
                                      .get()               // Specifies that GET method will be used.
                                      .uri("/test")        // Specifies the path.
                                      .responseSingle((res, body) -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(res), body.defaultIfEmpty(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER))),   // Receives the response body.
                                      (tuple1, tuple2) -> StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(tuple1.getT2().nioBuffer()).toString()
                          ).block();

        assertEquals("compressed response", response);

        server.disposeNow();          // Stops the server and releases the resources.
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0

at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.ensureAccessible(AbstractByteBuf.java:1454)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.checkIndex(AbstractByteBuf.java:1383)
at io.netty.buffer.CompositeByteBuf.nioBuffer(CompositeByteBuf.java:1663)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.nioBuffer(AbstractByteBuf.java:1231)
at io.spring.workshop.reactornetty.http.HttpCompressionTests.lambda$httpCompressionTest$4(HttpCompressionTests.java:59)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$null$45(Mono.java:5073)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:130)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:251)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:336)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:101)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onNext(FluxDoFinally.java:130)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:184)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:128)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260)
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:142)
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473)
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:702)
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:280)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

I have tried retaining my first response ByteBuf and that seems to work but then I will have to manually decrement reference counts which I feel may lead to Mem leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Reactor Netty will automatically release the `ByteBuf` if it is not consumed. You can disable this automatic release with invoking `body.retain()`, however once you finish with the `ByteBuf`, it is your responsibility to release it. The code above can be modified like this:

```
.responseSingle((res, body) -> Mono.zip(Mono.just(res), body.retain().defaultIfEmpty(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER)))   // Receives the response body.
```

More can be found in the [javadoc](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/ByteBufMono.html#retain--)